# How to download and unzip a sitemap gz file in c#?

Tags: c#, gzip

I need to download and unzip a sitemap.xml file that is compressed (maybe tar + gzip?) into a sitemap.xml.gz

From Windows I use 7zip. But note that the gz contains a directory with the same name of the zipped file (maybe due to tar + gx)

How can I do in c#?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [GZip Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) class to unzip the XML document.

Something like:

```
var file = File.Open("C:\test.xml.gz", FileMode.Open);
var zip = new GZipStream(file, CompressionMode.Decompress);
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(zip);
```

**Edit**

To be more clean with our IDisposables:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
using(var file = File.Open("C:\test.xml.gz", FileMode.Open))
using(var zip = new GZipStream(file, CompressionMode.Decompress))
{
    doc.Load(zip);
}
```

Comment: I would wrap the streams in using statements, but otherwise spot on.