# Extract All gz files inside a folder in C#

Tags: c#, batch-file, gzip

I am working on a application and need to extract the gz files inside a folder.

what I need is a c# script that can loop all gz files in a given folder and extract them into the same folder.

I know there are some libraries for this, But I could not able to get them work for gz, I got them working for zip though.

Or if there are any other solution for the same i.e if batch script can be created that can use WinRar command line utility to achieve the same. I don't know just an Idea if possible.

Note: I think I have to drop that second option- WinRar command is able to handle only RAR files.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download and unzip a sitemap gz file in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573269/how-to-download-and-unzip-a-sitemap-gz-file-in-c)

Comment: What's the problem? Do you have trouble iterating over all the files in the directory or is unzipping the gz file what's causing trouble?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Unzipping is gz file is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it solved. Thanks MichelZ for showing the way to go. I got the 7-zip command line version to done the trick for me.

```
@REM ------- BEGIN demo.cmd ----------------
@setlocal
@echo off
set path="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\";%path%
for /F %%i in ('dir /s/b *.gz') do call :do_extract "%%i"
for /F %%i in ('dir /s/b *.zip') do call :do_extract "%%i"
goto :eof

:do_extract
pushd %~dp1
7z e %1 -y
popd
REM ------- END demo.cmd ------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this as a batch file with winrar's "unrar" commandline freeware:

```
@REM ------- BEGIN demo.cmd ----------------
@setlocal
@echo off
set path="C:\Program Files\WinRAR\";%path%
for /F %%i in ('dir /s/b *.gz') do call :do_extract "%%i"
goto :eof

:do_extract
echo %1
mkdir %~1.extracted
pushd %~1.extracted
unrar e %1
popd

REM ------- END demo.cmd ------------------
```

Courtesy of: http://www.respower.com/page_tutorial_unrar

Comment: Thanks for this, Can you please help me running this bat file. I mean What should be the command to run this from command prompt? How do I pass the path of the folder where gz resides?

Comment: That would just take the "current folder", so would have to copy the batch file into the same folder as your *.gz, and then run it from there

Comment: I got this error: "xxxx" is not RAR archieve. However if I right click that my gz file and click extract here It got extracted successfully.

Comment: very sorry for this, i just read that the command line version of unrar is just able to handle .rar archives, unlike the Windows RAR program :(

Comment: I wanted to edit answer but I am getting "suggested edit queue is full". So anyway anyone having trouble decompressing gz with above code should replace unrar with winrar only and it will work, though it shows the UI while extracting its fine with me. You can also comment mkdir/pushd/popd if you want all operations in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest something like below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\something",
                            "*.gz", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                        select new
                        {
                            File = file,
                        };

            foreach (var f in files)
            {
                Process.Start("c:\winrar.exe", f.File);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0} files found and extracted!", 
                files.Count().ToString());
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException UAEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(UAEx.Message);
        }
        catch (PathTooLongException PathEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(PathEx.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

> NOTE: Please replace paths and winrar.exe parameters yourself with
>   correct one.

Comment: Directory.EnumerateFiles method doesn't seems to be there .net 3.5. How can I get this work in .net 3.5?

Comment: @Ankit, you can use Directory.GetFiles (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) in .net 3.5

Answer (score -1):

```
@setlocal
@echo off
set path="C:\Program Files\WinRAR\";%path%
for /F %%i in ('dir /s/b *.gz') do call :do_extract "%%i"
goto :eof

:do_extract
echo %1
mkdir %~1.extracted
pushd %~1.extracted
Winrar e %1
popd
```